# Python scrapy get detail from a table list

Tags: python, scrapy

I need the ISBN Number from a table... I tried some things like that example i show now, but it doesnt work to get the ISBN.

My Idea was, run all tr in for loop to get each td in there.
Than, if i found "ISBN" in one td, get the next td and the .span text from it, cause there is the number.

```
for tr in response.css('.ry-product-details__fullscreen-scrollable table tr'):
        td = tr.css('::text')[0].extract().strip()
        print(td)
        if "ISBN" in td:
            isbn = tr.css('td .span::text')[0].extract().strip()
            print(isbn)
```

The table looks like that (image) [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxDBC.png)

The table code looks like that

```
<table class="table ry-table ry-content-page__table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bluetooth</td>
            <td><span>Ja</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EAN / ISBN-13</td>
            <td><span>0888462149143, 5055887319009, 0888462149082</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ..... some more here ...
        </tr>
```

So i need this td span text there in the same tr where ISBN is found.
But also a problem is, it looks like that the `if "ISBN" in td:` doesnt work cause there is sometimes this "-" after it...

Comment: the dot before span means you are looking for class span and that is not what you want...in the css selector try to use only 'span::text()'

Comment: Thanks... my fail.. so my idea was correct, thanks, it worked without the "." before the span

Comment: no worries, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
   scrapy shell 
In [1]: body=''' <tr>
       ...:             <td>Bluetooth</td>
       ...:             <td><span>Ja</span></td>
       ...:         </tr>
       ...:         <tr>
       ...:             <td>EAN / ISBN-13</td>
       ...:             <td><span>0888462149143, 5055887319009, 08884
       ...: 62149082</span></td>
       ...:         </tr>'''
    In [2]: from scrapy import Selector

    In [3]: sel = Selector(text=body, type="html")
    In [4]: sel.xpath("//tr[contains(., 'ISBN')]/td[2]/span/text()").extract()
    Out[5]: ['0888462149143, 5055887319009, 0888462149082']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath:

```
response.xpath('//td[.="EAN / ISBN-13"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').get()
```